# How to get the current Activity from a Composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I need to call this function to show an interstitial ad from a button click inside a composable function, which expects an activity for the `show()` method:

```
fun showInterstitial() {
    if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd?.show(this)
    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "The interstitial ad wasn't ready yet.")
    }
}
```

How can I get the current activity and replace the `this` part?

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: The '`the`' part? Do you mean "the '`this`' part"?

Comment: val activity = LocalContext.current as AppCompatActivity

Comment: @MARSK Sorry, yes, `this`.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Can't use LocalContext since I need to make this a composable function then, in which case I can't call it from a button.

Comment: Gabirelle Mariotti? I think that's Philip. Anyway, I think you wish to use it inside the `onClick` of a Button. Well, then initialise just before the button within the Composable scope, storing it in a variable then use it in the onClick. Following Philip's answer.

Comment: Ok I didn't see Gabirelle's comment

Comment: @RawHasan Why you can't use it inside a composable?

Comment: Can't use it from `onClick` as it is, but definitely from a Composable. In fact, it can be used only within a Composable

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I need to call in from a button inside a composable, which won't accept any composable.

Comment: The '`Button`' won't accept a Composable?

Comment: @RawHasan Check the Philips's answer. it is the way.

Comment: You would want to remove the 'the' too, Gabrielle, before the time runs out.

Comment: Alright, too late.

Comment: @MARSK "button won't accept composible" = definitely from "onClick".

Comment: Yeah so that's what I mentioned in the comment above. Assign the context to a val just outside the button then use the val. And "button won't accept composible" does NOT equal that

Comment: Hey if I just copy paste Philip's answer into a new answer, would you mark my answer as the correct answer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get current context using `LocalContext`. With Compose usually it's gonna be your activity already, but to be sure you can unwrap it like this:

```
fun showInterstitial(context: Context) {
    val activity = context.findActivity()
}

@Composable
fun View() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Button(onClick = {
        val activity = context.findActivity()
    }) {

    }
}

fun Context.findActivity(): AppCompatActivity? = when (this) {
    is AppCompatActivity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

---

If you need to use context inside your view model, or in an other place where your handler function is located, you can pass context to your handler function.

```
fun showInterstitial(context: Context) {
    val activity = context.findActivity()
}

@Composable
fun View() {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Button(onClick = {
        showInterstitial(context)
    }) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This is a brilliant solution, which worked perfectly! Thanks!! :)

Comment: In my case I had to replace `AppCompatActivity` with `ComponentActivity`.